# indexOf methods in if statement

Tags: methods, indexof

```
if(arr.indexOf(element))
if(arr.indexOf(element) !== -1)
if(arr.indexOf(element) > 0)
```

I thought that when I use `indexOf()` in an `if` statement, those if statements above would be the same, but I got a different result than I expected.

Is there anyone who knows the difference among these?

Comment: `indexOf` "inside if" is irrelevant. Only the results of such (and the incorrect expectation of usages are); replacing with the actual value would have the same effect. So what is the *value* that `indexOf` returns? Why does this *value* (and any resulting operation on such) *100% explain the behavior*?

Comment: I am just wondering if there is a certain element in the array and push that element in the new array.

Comment: Again, only the *result* of the indexOf is relevant to the question - [what does the *documentation* ay the behavior is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)? Since the value will be -1 if not found, >= 0 otherwise, it can be seen that all forms shown produce different logic behavior: `if(x)` - any return value except 0, meaning it was not found, or was found as not-the-first; `if(x !== -1)` - if the element was found; `if(x > 0)` - if the element was found and is *not* the first element. For values of `x` *read the documentation*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a JS question, All three are different.

There is no special logic for indexOf within an if statement. It is the same logic as ever. You just need to understand how indexOf() evaluates. The first checks if the index is truthy or falsey, so ONLY the first index would not qualify and all other indexes would pass. The second checks that it is not -1, anything would pass except values not in the array, and the third checks if the index of the element is greater than 0 so all pass except the first index and any element not in the index.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry. it is Javascript question. I was using those to check if there is a certain element in the array and push the element in the new array. so I just checked if there is the certain element, which mean I thought all those would be true but each behavior was different.

Comment: No need to apologize! Just read the documentation and work backwards from there. Array.contains() would be more relevant than the index of the elem in this case.